# matplotlib: 3d plot crosses the boundary (graphene dispersion)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have this following code which attempts to plot a function `+/- f` which defines the graphene dispersion in the momentum space.

```
# 3D Plot of graphene dispersion

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np

def sqrt(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)

def cos(x):
    return np.cos(x)

# Constants
a = 1.0
d = a*np.sqrt(3)
t = 2.7
t2 = 0.5

print "The display is not up to the mark! Modification needed.\n" 


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-2.0*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2.0*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 0.1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

f=t*sqrt(3.0+2.0*cos(a*x)+4.0*cos(a/2.0*x)*cos(d/2.0*y))

surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)


f=-f
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim3d(-3.0, 3.0)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=1.0, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

which gives me a plot that overflows the z-axis boundary :

[image]

However, keeping the same function definition and using gnuplot or Mathematica I was able to produce this

[image: Source: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/can-the-color-in-meshstyle-be-specified-by-a-colorfunction-such-as-sunsetcolor]

and this [image: Source:]

Can any of the last two be reproduced by using python with matplotlib?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want, since you explicitly set the z-limits inside the range of the data (`ax.set_zlim3d(-3.0, 3.0)`), but I get a similar plot simply by commenting out this line (and picking a nicer colormap):

```
# 3D Plot of graphene dispersion

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np

sqrt = np.sqrt
cos = np.cos

# Constants
a = 1.0
d = a*np.sqrt(3)
t = 2.7
t2 = 0.5

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-2.0*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2.0*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 0.1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

f=t*sqrt(3.0+2.0*cos(a*x)+4.0*cos(a/2.0*x)*cos(d/2.0*y))

surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('PuOr'),
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)


f=-f
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('PuOr'),
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
#ax.set_zlim3d(-3.0, 3.0)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=1.0, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

(Note also that you don't need to define a wrapper function to create an alias to `np.sqrt`, etc. Functions are first class objects in Python and you can simply assign a name: `sqrt = np.sqrt`.)